# How to resolve 'UsePythonVersion@0' task failure on self hosted agent

Tags: python-3.x, linux, azure-devops, github-actions, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to create a simple pipeline where python application code will be pulled from github enterprise and will be executed on the agent server itself. Here I am using `Self hosted agent` on a Linux VM.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - refs/tags/*
      - feature*

stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature')))
    jobs:
      - job: 'RunDeploymentCommandJob'
        displayName: Deploying job
        pool:
          name: Ppe-Gear-Price-Agent-Pool
        steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.6'  # Use Python 3.x
              addToPath: true
          - script: |
              cd gear-price-publisher
              # Install dependencies if needed
              pip install -r requirements.txt
              # Run the Python code
              gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:80 controller:app
            displayName: 'Run Python Code'
```

While code is successfully checked out Github Enterprise, `UsePythonVersion` task is getting failed with the below error for Gihub:

```
##[warning]You should provide GitHub token if you want to download a python release. Otherwise you may hit the GitHub anonymous download limit.
##[error]Failed to download Python from the Github Actions python registry (https://github.com/actions/python-versions). Error: AggregateError
##[error]Version spec 3.6 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
```

Could you please suggest on this.

Thanks

Comment: On the Linux agent, are you able to directly access the web `https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases/download/3.6.8-96689/python-3.6.8-linux-20.04-x64.tar.gz`? If you can, try to create github PAT and add `githubToken: '$(token)'` to the task. Please add the errors if it fails. You could need to prepare the tool cache following [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-python-version-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#how-can-i-configure-a-self-hosted-agent-to-use-this-task)

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Yes I am able to do the wget successfully but do I really need to create a personal github account  and pat for this as my organization is using github enterprise or is there any better alternate approach for pipeline ?

Comment: Thanks for confirming the network to github is OK. Checked on my side, github PAT is not needed. I'm able to execute the task on Ubuntu self-hosted agent, i will add the detail steps in the reply, thanks.

Comment: How can I debug why it's not working for me. Following the same steps.

Comment: After the task, please check if the python package is downloaded, and on the agent machine, the `tool cache` folder structure is prepared automatically(can refer to my 2nd screenshot). If the error is different on your log, please share it in the statement, thanks.

Comment: No it's not. That's the error, right ? Error message is clearly saying "failed to download" followed by the error "Version spec 3.6 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory" which is obvious due to previous error.

Comment: Try to download the pacakge manually on the `agent machine` and put the `gz` file in location `/home/wade/myagent/_work/_temp/python-3.6.15-linux-20.04-x64.tar.gz` (change the path and package version to yours), the task is extracting from the location. If the error still exists and it's blocked by the download(even with the github token), you could contact local network team. In addition, i created the ubuntu agent on Azure VM, maybe you can give a try.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT did you try your steps for self hosted agent ?

Comment: Yes, the step shared is from my self-hosted ubuntu 20.04 agent.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT I am not sure if I am misunderstanding it but as per official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-python-version-v0?view=azure-pipelines python download will not work with self hosted agent. So how it worked for you ?

Comment: i also notice the info on the doc. But checked on both `Ubuntu` and `Windows` self-hosted agent, it will try to download the installation package, complete installation and prepare the tool cache. It appears the doc is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Linux agent(mine is ubuntu 20.04) is able to access the python download page `https://github.com/actions/python-versions`, you can use the task in pipeline:

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.6'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'
```

It will download the python package and try to prepare the `tool cache` folder structure for you:

[image]

The `tool cache` structure on the agent machine:
[image]

To resolve the error in the log `./python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, we can link it manually via command(change the path to your own):

```
sudo ln -s ~/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.6.15/x64/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

After it's done, run again the pipeline:

[image]

Comment: I tried my pipeline with a different agent pool and I got the logs as per the first screenshot shared by where it tried to download the python package, So seems it's some environment issue on my agent/server (proxy, proxybypass or something else).

Comment: Yes, it could be. On the new agent, if you are able to download the python package, you can follow the step to use the task. :)

Comment: I didn't try in on a new agent . I tried on a agent used for another application so I can't use that for sure but atleast now I know there's something in the environment.